# Cannot start/restart PHP 7.2 FPM service (CentOS 7, Apache)

Tags: php, apache, service, centos, fpm

I am trying to start PHP-FPM but I keep failing.

`# sudo systemctl status rh-php72-php-fpm`

The result is:

```
[0m rh-php72-php-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rh-php72-php-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 2020-07-06 09:51:09 KST; 18s ago
  Process: 10442 ExecStart=/opt/rh/rh-php72/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 10442 (code=exited, status=127)

 706 09:51:09 myserver systemd[1]: Starting The PHP FastCGI Process Manager...
 706 09:51:09 myserver php-fpm[10442]: /opt/rh/rh-php72/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm: symbol lookup error: /opt/rh/rh-php72/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm: undefi..._jit_exec
 706 09:51:09 myserver systemd[1]: rh-php72-php-fpm.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
 706 09:51:09 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
 706 09:51:09 myserver systemd[1]: Unit rh-php72-php-fpm.service entered failed state.
 706 09:51:09 myserver systemd[1]: rh-php72-php-fpm.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

It seems like I have a directory link issue, but have no idea.
Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could be a dependency issue. https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/755. Try installing/updating libpcre3.

Comment: share `systemctl status rh-php72-php-fpm -l` command output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a library issue.

Thanks @Jeemusu